# Python change xml attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2
Is it posible to change xml file using python when

```
<Label name="qotl_type_label" position="910,980" font="headline_light" />
```

Search by name attribute and then change position?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What I can understand is that you want to change an xml file (how? change what to what?), but only if.. what? Do you need assistance with checking if the a satisfies your requirement or with changing the file, or both?

Comment: I wanted to change attribute in file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module to parse the XML, locate the `Label` element and change the `position` attribute via [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) property:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>>
>>> s = '<root><Label name="qotl_type_label" position="910,980" font="headline_light" /></root>'
>>>
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> label = root.find(".//Label[@name='qotl_type_label']")
>>> label.attrib['position'] = 'new,position'
>>> ET.tostring(root)
'<root><Label font="headline_light" name="qotl_type_label" position="new,position" /></root>'
```

Note that the order of attributes is not preserved, attributes are unordered *by definition*.

Comment: Is there a way to search only by name attribute? This will be messy in my program.

Comment: @KubaJanek I've done exactly that in the code sample - see the "find()" call where we check the `name` attribute value.